# Sustain an http connection while django processes a big request (20mins+)

Tags: django, http

I've got a django site that is producing a csv download. The content of the csv is dictated by user defined parameters. It's possible that users will set parameters that require significant thinking time on the server. I need a way of sustaining the http connection so the browser doesn't kick up an error message. I heard that it's possible to send intermittent http headers to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction to set this up on a django site?

(unfortunatly I'm stuck with the possibility of slow reports - improving my sql won't mitigate this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do it online. Trigger an offline task, use a bit of Javascript to repeatedly call a view that checks if the task has finished, and redirect to the finished file when it's ready.

Comment: +1 Further to the above - OP might like to consider sending an email to the user instead (attaching the content) or in addition (as a notification).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of blocking the user and it's browser for 20 minutes (which is not a good idea) do the time-consuming task in the background. When the task will finish and generate the result simply notify the user so that he/she will just need to download the ready result.

Comment: You might want to use a queue processing system to do this - django-celery might be helpful here. Once ten users submit 20-minute tasks everyone has a 200-minute task... Email notification is a common pattern for tasks like this.